# TLS-PSK over TOR python

Tags: client-server, wrapper, tor, tls-psk

I am currently trying to create a "TOR version" of a service I created, running with TLS. I want to perform  mutual authentication of both parties ; client and server.
I thought about using **TLS-PSK over TOR**, which would gives me the properties I desire, especially eavesdropping prevention.

I wanted to use the socket library and to double wrap a socket instance using first the ssl library then to do the same thing with TOR, but it looks like there is no library existing allowing me to do the second wrapping.

Do you have any idea about existing libraries allowing me to do something like that ?